# Heatmap correlation using values of column?

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation

Suppose I have the following data of repeat observations for US states with some value of interest:

```
US_State Value
Alabama  1
Alabama  10
Alabama  9
Michigan 8
Michigan 9
Michigan 2
...
```

How can I generate pairwise correlations for Value between all the US_State combinations? I've tried a few different things (pivot, groupby, and more), but I can't seem to wrap my head around the proper approach.

The ideal output would look like:

```
          Alabama   Michigan    ...
Alabama      1          0.5
Michigan     0.5        1
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way utilising Pandas to its extents, but this is only under the assumption that each state in the input dataset has the same number of observations, otherwise correlation coefficient does not really make sense and the results will become a bit funky.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['US_State'] = ["Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Michigan", "Michigan", "Michigan", "Oregon", "Oregon", "Oregon"]
df['Value'] = [1, 10, 9, 8, 9, 2, 6, 1, 2]

pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("US_State")['Value'].apply(lambda x: list(x))).T.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(*x), axis=0).corr()
```

which results into

```
US_State   Alabama  Michigan    Oregon
US_State                              
Alabama   1.000000 -0.285578 -0.996078
Michigan -0.285578  1.000000  0.199667
Oregon   -0.996078  0.199667  1.000000
```

What the code basically does is it collects the data for each state into a single cell as a list, transposes the dataframe to make the states columns and then expands the collected cell of list data into dataframe rows for each state. Then you can just call the standard `corr()` method of pandas dataframe.

Comment: Ugh what the heck this is such a good answer! I swear I hit like small components of this in every which way. I was actually writing out a manual loop to subset based on combinations, calculate correlations, and store it as a matrix when your answer came along. So elegant! If you don't mind me asking - what is this part pd.Series(*x), axis=0) doing (specifically the (*x)?

Comment: Thanks, no problem. The asterisk basically means take all the values from the list as input argument, have a look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3. In this example it's not really necessary tbh, equivalent way is to write `pd.Series(x[0])`, since there is only 1 argument. Because the input argument `x` in the lambda is basically a list-like of a list, we just need it to be a list and the asterisk does it for us.

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Thanks for the explanation and link :D

Answer (score 1):

Pandas DataFrame has a built-in correlation matrix function. You will somehow need to get your data into a DataFrame (takes numpy objects, plain dict (shown), etc).

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

data = {'AL': [1,10,9],
        'MI': [8,9,2],
        'CO': [11,5,17]
        }

df = DataFrame(data)

corrMatrix = df.corr()
print(corrMatrix)

# optional heatmap
import seaborn as sn
sn.heatmap(corrMatrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm')
```

```
          AL        MI        CO
AL  1.000000 -0.285578 -0.101361
MI -0.285578  1.000000 -0.924473
CO -0.101361 -0.924473  1.000000
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response and this is what I understood it should be doing, but I couldn't get my data to look like your df. When I try to pivot it - df.pivot(columns = 'US_State', values = 'Value') I get a bunch of NaN (rather than them all having the same number of rows. Am I missing something with the index?

Comment: You can add an index "index" being the rank within group: `df2['index'] = df2.groupby('State')["Value"].rank()`
Then `df2.pivot(columns='State',values='Value', index='index')`

Comment: Should work but getting 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'. Likely a specific issue with my data and not generalizable! So I'll keep at it - thanks for the answers :)